# Entries form in control panel won't display if I have a Matrix field enabled

Tags: matrix, control-panel

I'm new to Craft, and have a local installation of version 2.6.2789

I have created a section with its own field layout. Everytime I enable a matrix field in the field layout, the section entry form won't display anything.

Attached is the screenshot of the entry form itself.

[image]

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What browser and version are you using? Check the browser requirements for using the control panel here: https://craftcms.com/docs/requirements#cp-browser-requirements

Comment: I'm using Chrome 51 as well as Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens if xdebug is installed with the default nesting limit. You can either disable xdebug as PHP itself does not have a function nesting limit,

change the setting in your php.ini:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 400
```

or in your PHP code:

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 400);
```